# Wordpress API hook

Tags: plugins

i want to be able to send JSON data to my Wordpress plugin, can i register an API hook, or do i have to post directly to my plugins file ? There must be a better way.

I have looked trough the docs, and i can't seem to find an API hook that my plugin can subscribe to, which i can send POST data to.

I seem to recall, that it was possible to post to some admin URL, which had a hook.

Answer (score 0):

You would register your ajax-rendering code with the action `wp_ajax_{my_action_goes_here}` for logged-in users, or `wp_ajax_nopriv_{my_action_goes_here}` for users *not* logged in.  Something like:

```
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_top_4_posts", function() {
    $q = new WP_Query(array(
        "posts_per_page" => 4
    ));
    exit(json_encode($q->posts));
});
```

This would go in a theme functions file or a plugin of your choice (any location that is evaluated before templates are pulled in).  Then, your ajax would call out to the url `admin_url("admin-ajax.php")` and you would pass in an `action` parameter of "get_top_4_posts" (or whatever action name you end up using).

Comment: Which URL would i send my POST requests to in that case ? www.site.com/wp-admin? and how would i get the POST data

Comment: The URL is <url>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php, which you should get by using the Wordpress function `admin_url("admin-ajax.php")` if possible (future-proofs you against your domain or URL changing on you).  Within your function, you would simply reference the `$_POST[]` array (e.g. `$_POST['action']` should give you the action that got you to that ajax function).